# AngularJs with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code because I want inlude the Google maps in my webApp but don't work. This is the page html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/mappa/lodash.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/mappa/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

         <div>
              <ui-gmap-google-map center=map.center zoom=map.zoom style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></ui-gmap-google-map>                    
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my controller in AngularJs:

```
var modulo = angular.module('progetto', ['ngRoute', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

modulo.controller('descriptionController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
     $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };

    }).
        error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.listaEventi = "Request failed";
        });
```

Where is the error? I think that i import exact library!

Comment: Please include the error

Comment: Also, if that's all of your JS code...your call to .error is on the controller itself...

Comment: it don't show the error! anyway this is a piece of code!

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing quotes around your html attributes...
2. You're missing ng-app
3. You're missing ng-controller
4. You're calling .error on your controller (?)
5. You need to define this css rule:

   ```
   .angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }
   ```

Inline style on your directive is *not* good enough.

6. Please check your js error console next time. Your statement of "there are no errors" is most likely not true.

Here's a working fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/ybtn4kn2/

Comment: I find the solution...first of the all this is a piece of the code anyway i didn't define the css rule...otherwise all ok!

Comment: OK...you should post your code verbatim next time if you want us to effectively help you then. Please mark this answer correct if it's helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten your

```
<div ng-controller="descriptionController">
```

And you will need to pass in the library to the controller

```
.controller("descriptionController", function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi)
```

Comment: I use ng-controller="descriptionController" but i omitted it in copy XD